# How to set the language for the ggplot axis labels in shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I used RMarkdown to create a shiny dashboard, which contains some ggpolts.
I have added the below lines to set my language in English.

`Sys.setenv("LANGUAGE"="En")`
`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")`

And when I run my .rmd file from RStudio the axis labels and legend are in English (like in picture below).

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQu1e.png)

However, if I open the dashboard using the link, then the language turns to Chinese, and since the dashboard cannot display Chinese characters, weird blocks are contained in the label and legend (like in picture below).

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgam8.png)

So can anybody help me, to let my dashboard **always show the English** labels and legend?

Also, if somebody can advise me, how to split the Weekdays into 2 categories, ie. **Weekdays** and **Weekend** (so not Mon, Tue,...), it will also help me a lot.

I used *mutate()* function to get the weekdays:

`mutate(Weekdays = weekdays(date))`

Comment: Try adding these to your R profile. When your run a `.Rmd` dashboard file, Rstudio opens another R session in the background which does not share the same environmental variables, so you need to set it in `Rprofile`.

Comment: And be careful about which directory houses the  `.Rprofile` settings. The Rstudio defaults are different than those used by RGUI (Windows) or R.app(MacOS).

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that I can get answers so quickly. And it really worked! Thank you very much!